# Why I can't use the tools in the xml in Kotlin?

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to use tools:text but I have an error, do I have to import something?

````
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRealName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:text="Prueba de nombre"
        />

        />
    ```
````

Comment: Put the cursor on `tools` and hit Alt+Enter and choose the option to add it.

Comment: add xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" to your root layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to add following in your parent layout of your xml

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Hope, this will help you.